# Swiper - Strange visual artefacts in final 2 items of carousel when setting .swiper-slide width to less than 100%

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

In order to have the edges of the previous/next carousel items to show within Slider, I am reducing the `.swiper-slide` size. There are two ways of achieving this that I have tried:

1. setting `.swiper-slide` width to 90%
2. setting the `slidesPerView` param to 1.1

Both work nicely, but the final two items in the carousel show stange visual artefacts. The background of the container appears to overlap and intersect the slider. Images below (first in each example is as it is expected to render, second is with glitch). The visual glitch is cleared with a click, but still undesirable:

[image: As expected]
[image: With visual glitch]
[image: As expected 2]
[image]

These are my Slider params

```
const params = {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 50,
  speed: 400,
  centeredSlides: true,
  initialSlide: this.props.latestQuestionIndex,
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  breakpoints: {
    768: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 30
    },
    425: {
      slidesPerView: 1.1,
      spaceBetween: 10
    }
  },
  on: {
    slideChange: () =>
      this.state.swiper && this.setState({ currentIndex: this.state.swiper.activeIndex })
  }
};
```

Is there another method of allowing for overlap of the edges of other carousel images, or a fix for this visual glitch?